# Keras custom Optimizer ValueError: Missing learning rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, optimization

I'm trying to create a custom optimizer using the Keras library in TensorFlow. I'm coding the optimizer from scratch. It's showing the following error:

`ValueError: Missing learning rate, please set self.learning_rate at optimizer creation time.`

In my optimizer's creation, I'm adding the `self.learning_rate` and still the problem persists. Here's my code for the **init** function of the optimizer:

```
def __init__(self, lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,
                 momentum=0.0, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, name='AdamSGD', **kwargs):
        super(AdamSGD, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.iterations = K.variable(0, dtype='int64', name='iterations')
        self.learning_rate = K.variable(lr, name='lr')
        self.beta_1 = K.variable(beta_1, name='beta_1')
        self.beta_2 = K.variable(beta_2, name='beta_2')
        self.momentum = K.variable(momentum, name='momentum')
        self.epsilon = epsilon or K.epsilon()
        self.decay = K.variable(decay, name='decay')
```

This is how I'm compiling my model and where the error is being triggered:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=AdamSGD(lr=0.01),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

The entire error:

```
     24 # Compile the model
     25 model.compile(
---> 26     optimizer=AdamSGD(lr=0.01),
     27     loss='categorical_crossentropy',
     28     metrics=['accuracy']

     24         self.iterations = K.variable(0, dtype='int64', name='iterations')
---> 25         self.learning_rate = K.variable(lr, name='lr')
     26         self.beta_1 = K.variable(beta_1, name='beta_1')
     27         self.beta_2 = K.variable(beta_2, name='beta_2')

     60     try:
---> 61       if getattr(self, name) is value:
     62         # Short circuit for `self.$x = self.$x`.
     63         return

    330     def learning_rate(self):
    331         if not hasattr(self, "_learning_rate") or self._learning_rate is None:
--> 332             raise ValueError(
    333                 "Missing learning rate, please set self.learning_rate at"
    334                 " optimizer creation time."

ValueError: Missing learning rate, please set self.learning_rate at optimizer creation time.
```

If someone has any suggestions or knows where I'm going wrong, please let me know as I'm stuck on this error for quite some time now.

Comment: the error message is pretty clear: `if not hasattr(self, "_learning_rate"): raise ...`... so to me, seems he's looking for `self._learning_rate` and not `self.learning_rate`

Comment: ```self._learning_rate``` worked, but now I've some totally new problems which I need to take care of, thank you for the answer. Do you have any suggestions where I can properly learn to make my own custom keras optimizer, given that I've worked out the maths and just want to implement it in Keras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is counter intuitive, but you should "simply" set the attribute `self._learning_rate` in your constructor. You can do so with the function `self._build_learning_rate(learning_rate)`.

```
class AdamSGD(keras.optimizers.Optimizer):
     def __init__(self, lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,
                     momentum=0.0, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, name='AdamSGD', **kwargs):
        super(AdamSGD, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.iterations = K.variable(0, dtype='int64', name='iterations')
        self._learning_rate = self._build_learning_rate(lr)
        self.beta_1 = K.variable(beta_1, name='beta_1')
        self.beta_2 = K.variable(beta_2, name='beta_2')
        self.momentum = K.variable(momentum, name='momentum')
        self.epsilon = epsilon or K.epsilon()
        self.decay = K.variable(decay, name='decay')
```

This function enables the optimizer to accept both a [schedule](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules) or a float value as learning rate.

You might also need to implement some extra methods, see this [comment in the code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.12.0/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py#L1056):

> #### Creating a custom optimizer
>
> If you intend to create your own optimization algorithm, please inherit from
> this class and override the following methods:
>
> - `build`: Create your optimizer-related variables, such as `momentums` in SGD optimizer.
> - `update_step`: Implement your optimizer's updating logic.
> - `get_config`: serialization of the optimizer, include all hyper parameters.

Comment: It's working now, although I now have a totally new error: "NotImplementedError: in user code:", do you have any source or suggestions where I can learn to make custom keras optimizers properly? I have worked out the maths for my optimizer where I've integrated Adam with SDG, but I'm facing difficulties in coding it in Keras and TensorFlow

Comment: You need to implement some specific methods, see this [comment](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.12.0/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py#L1056).